# Testing RPC clients for runtime upgrades in advance

Tags: runtime-upgrade

Is there a way to test Polkadot and Kusama RPC client applications for a runtime upgrade before it gets enacted? i.e. Is there a way to emulate the upgraded runtime in a sandbox environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what you want here, for test a runtime upgrade or a polkadot rpc client which will connect to the new runtime.

usually before on-chain upgrade in polkadot/kusama we use [polkadot-launch](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-launch) to launch a test-net locally and do whatever test first

and for test a runtime upgrade you need to integrate [try-runtime](https://docs.substrate.io/how-to-guides/v3/tools/try-runtime/) into your parachain nodes and test locally first

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's the latter, testing an RPC client that will connect to the new runtime. I think `polkadot-launch` is what I'm after, I'll give it a shot, thanks!